# Get inputs from multiple textfields to array and insert to db field

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, dreamweaver

I have an order form. It has 10 textfields for the user to input a quantity. How do you store the inputs to an array and insert to a db field(separated by comas)? Note: It is NOT required to input on all the textfields. For instance, the inputs are 1,2,3,4..it should appear in the db field also 1,2,3,4

examples and descriptions would be great. I'm relatively new to this.

Comment: use implode to make the input a quantity a string with delimeter , then insert into the db.

Comment: @SuchitKumar Can you demonstrate? i've got no idea how to do it.sorry

Comment: see in answer i hace echoed $data you need to insert it using sql to your table ,no need to echo. @kim

Comment: everyone thanks for answering but the chosen one was the easiest to understand for me. I'll take note of them though. have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose this is your **form:** if you are only bothering about order array nothing else like corresponding key.

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="order[]" />
  <input type="text" name="order[]" />
  <input type="text" name="order[]" />
  <input type="text" name="order[]" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

your **submit.php:**

```
     <?php 
       $data ="";
  foreach($_POST["order"] as $key=>$val){
    if(isset($val) && $val !="")
      $data.=$val.",";
  }
   $data=trim($data);
    echo $data;// use data
```

**Note:**  do not use mysql use PDO or mysqli instead. mysql is deprecated.

Comment: it worked thanks a lot but it leaves comas to the blank textfields. how to fix that?i have 10 textfields but if only 2 have inputs, it results to 1,2,,,,,,,,

Comment: @kim use trim for this:$data = implode(',',$_POST["order"]);
echo trim($data,',');

Comment: In mysql field it still appears like that 1,2,,,,,,,,

Comment: Hi. i just tested again. If the inputs from textfield skips in between, like input 1,2,3 from textfld1,textfld2, and textfld5, it still results to 1,2,,,3

Comment: can you tell me why you are storing like this.

Comment: it's for school.and this is the only way i can think of when ordering.you see i'm not trying to follow the common right way to order a product(add to cart).the product names are in checkbox and that inserts to a field.the only way i know to store the equivalent quantity of product is to insert in another field.

Comment: if it is not for commercial use then fine.

Answer (score 3):

So, let's say you have a table with four text fields - `fieldOne`, `fieldTwo`, `fieldThree`, `fieldFour`.

Your `html form` should look like this (i'm skipping irrelevant parts).

```
<form method="POST">
    <textarea name='data[fieldOne]'></textarea>
    <textarea name='data[fieldTwo]'></textarea>
    <textarea name='data[fieldThree]'></textarea>
    <textarea name='data[fieldFour]'></textarea>
</form>
```

Now, your `PHP` code:

```
$data = $_POST['data']; // PHP converts names like data[fieldOne] into arrays.

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $fieldNames[] = "`{$key}`";    //field names for our insert statement - `fieldOne`, `fieldTwo`, etc...
    $values[":{$key}"] = strip_tags($value); 
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `tableName` (".implode(', ', $fieldNames).") VALUES (".implode(", ", array_keys($values)).")"; // If you're not using PDO and prepared statements you're doing it wrong, so i absolutely recommend you learning that if you haven't already.
$stmt->execute($values);
```

That should do the trick.
Notice, using prepared statements frees you from manually escaping your data. However, if you're concerned about `XSS` attacks, you still should use `strip_tags` of a `filter` extension.

Comment: Arent u missing a `:` in front of the `array_keys($values)`?

Comment: Nope, because of `$values[":{$key}"]`

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<form action="my_page_that_processes_orders.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="order[product1]" />
  <input type="text" name="order[product2]" />
  <input type="text" name="order[product3]" />
  <input type="text" name="order[product4]" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

`my_page_that_processes_orders.php`

```
$data = $_POST["order"];// Advisable to perform checks for security reasons (not going to do it)

$aux = '';
foreach($data as $product => $qty) {
 // Do whatever you please with the data.
 $aux .= "$product $qty,"; // For instance.
}

$string_to_insert = rtrim($aux, ",");
// Insert it in DB or do more processing stuff.
```

Hope it helps.

Kind regards.